# How to download list of the data based on id?

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I have two http addresses. The first allows me to download the entire list using /findAll, but second one does not have this query. It allows to download only the selected station by the id of the first address /{stationId}. So I can download only one station in one query. How to download the entire list of the second address by URLSession? Loop?

Adresses:
First:

```
http://api.gios.gov.pl/pjp-api/rest/station/findAll
```

Second:

```
http://api.gios.gov.pl/pjp-api/rest/station/sensors/{stationId}
```

It is not possible to use the /findAll query in the second one.

First (Stations):

```
func fetchStations(url: URL) -> Observable<[Station]> {
    
    return Observable.create { observer -> Disposable in
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)
    { data, _, _ in
    
    guard let data = data else {
        observer.onError(NSError(domain: "", code: -1, userInfo: nil))
        return
    }
        
        do {
            let stations = try JSONDecoder().decode([Station].self, from: data)
            observer.onNext(stations)
        } catch {
            observer.onError(error)
        }
    }
        task.resume()
        
        return Disposables.create {
                task.cancel()
            }
        }
}
```

Second (Sensors):

```
func fetchSensors(url: URL) -> Observable<[Sensor]> {
    
    return Observable.create { observer -> Disposable in
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)
    { data, _, _ in
    
    guard let data = data else {
        observer.onError(NSError(domain: "", code: -1, userInfo: nil))
        return
    }
        
        do {
            let sensors = try JSONDecoder().decode([Sensor].self, from: data)
            observer.onNext(sensors)
            print("API SERVICE:  \(sensors)")
        } catch {
            observer.onError(error)
        }
    }
        task.resume()
        
        return Disposables.create {
                task.cancel()
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second function will need input for `stationID`, and then make your final URL inside of function `baseURL + "sensors/" + stationID`.

Make sure your object have all required properties from API documentation

Comment: I know. And this is problem, because I need the whole list of sensors. One query gives me only sensors under station. For example just one, or two.  I need all sensors for all stations. It is possible to download all stations by /findAll query, but there is no possible to make same query for sensors.

Comment: Ah, then you will need to make a loop for stations to get all the sensors one by another